# Specialization of a Weak Entity in ER Diagram Modeling

Tags: entity-relationship, erd, object-oriented-database, weak-entity

I've been making ERD for quite some times but, I encountered a unique case now as follows*:

1. Every **Account** may do a **Registration**
2. Every **Registration** requires **Acceptance Period**
3. Every **Registration** requires at least 1 **Program** or more
4. There are **2 kinds** of **Registration**, **UUI Registration** and **SEMAS UI Registration**. A **Registration** can either be **UUI Registration** or **SEMAS UI Registration** but it can't be both (disjoint)
5. **SEMAS UI Registrasion** must be either a **SEMAS S1 Registration**, **SEMAS S2 Registration** or **SEMAS S3 Registration** (disjoint).
6. **UUI Registration** and **SEMAS S1 Registration** records the registrant **Prior School**
7. **SEMAS S2 Registration** and **SEMAS S3 Registration** records the registrant **Prior University**

From the description we know that **Registration** is a weak entity as it cannot exist without **Account**, **Acceptance Period** and **Program**. But **Registration** has specializations here.

So the question is:

1. Am I allowed to model **UUI Registration** and **SEMAS UI Registration** as subclasses of **Registration** which is a weak entity?
2. If it is allowed, how do I model them? As weak entities too or as strong entities?

Thank you for all of your help!

*Ignore attributes

Answer (score 1):

While weak entity sets have an existence dependency on their parent entity sets, existence dependencies don't automatically mean an entity set is a weak entity set. A regular entity set can be required to participate totally in a relationship, which similarly imposes an existence dependency.

To identify weak entity sets, look at how they're identified. A weak entity set's identity / primary key will be a superset of its parent's identity / primary key.

There's no restriction to prevent weak entity sets from having subtypes. However, I haven't seen any examples of how to represent them on ER diagrams. I'm inclined to draw them in the same way as their parent entity sets (i.e. as weak entity sets) since they have the same identity. Another reason is that in classic ER (before EER notation for subtyping), the only way to represent a subtype was as a weak entity set without a weak key.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't opened  stackoverflow for a long time. So, even though an entity existence depends on another entity, it's not always considered as weak entity? What if this is the case: `Building` has `rooms`. Without `building`, `rooms` could not exist. Are `rooms` weak entity?

Comment: If rooms are identified by their own attributes (e.g. a `room_id`), then `rooms` is a regular entity set. If rooms are partially identified by the building they're in (e.g. a composite key of `(building_id,room_number)`) then it's a weak entity set.

Comment: So, the main issue is the primary key then? Even though `rooms` existence depends on `building`, it will still be a regular entity if it has its own primary key which is independent from other entity's attribute. If this is the case, how do we identify that `rooms` depends on `building` to exist in the diagram?

Comment: The concept in ER is called participation - we would say that `rooms` participate fully in the relationship with `buildings` and it's indicated with a double line between the rectangle for `rooms` and the diamond for its relationship with `buildings`.